# Unusual behavior for loop with Find command using ksh

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, find, ksh

I am observing a very strange behavior in my KSH script and I am unable to figure out the reason behind it. I am hoping someone might have an explanation for this!

Script Flow:

1. Loop over files in a directory to create batch files for processing the input files in batches. Ex: Input Files

   ```
   sample_abc_20180910.txt
   sample_abc_20180911.txt

   sample_def_20180910.txt
   sample_def_20180911.txt;
   ```

Script loops over the files using the following command:

```
for f in `find $dataindir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "sample_*.txt" | sort -n`
```

this for loop works as expected - it picks up one file at a time and proceeds with the for loop.

2. Process checks that two files have "abc" in them and the other two have "def" in them.
3. Process creates project_1.batch containing the names of the two files in two separate lines.

   ```
   $cat project_1.batch
   $sample_abc_20180910.txt
   $sample_abc_20180911.txt
   ```

Similarly, process creates project_2.batch containing the names of the other two files in two separate lines.

4. Next I loop over the two .batch files and it runs as expected.
   The for loop picks up one .batch file at a time and proceeds...

   ```
   for bf in `find $dataindir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.batch" | sort -n`
       do
         echo $bf
         #intermediate process
       done
   ```
5. However, I iterate over the .batch files a second time in a separate for loop using the same command (but using a different for loop variable) and this time the results are weird! The for loop picks up both the .batch files at one go!

   ```
   for ef in `find $dataindir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.batch" | sort -n`
       do
         echo $ef
         #intermediate process
       done

   $/home/userdir/project/project_2.batch
   $/home/userdir/project/project_1.batch
   ```

Subsequently, when I try to run a cat on $ef inside the for loop, I get the error

```
cat: /home/userdir/project/project_2.batch
/home/userdir/project/project_1.batch: No such file or directory
```

^^^^ Note the new line character being included between the two file names.

Why is that the the for loop with find command works one time but not the other? I eventually has to use the following to make the script work, but why doesn't the find command work just like it did the previous time?!

```
for file in $dataindir/project_*.batch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you modify `IFS`, the Internal Field Separator that decides which characters to split your unquoted command expansions on:

```
$ grep '' *
hello.txt:hello
world.txt:world

$ for f in `find . -name '*.txt'`; do cat "$f"; done
hello
world

$ IFS=':'
(no output)

$ for f in `find . -name '*.txt'`; do cat "$f"; done
cat: ./hello.txt
./world.txt: No such file or directory
```

This is one of several reasons why you should avoid `for` loops over command expansions, and read NUL or linefeed separated entries with a `while read` loop instead.

Comment: You sir, are a genius!! I am setting IFS='|' before I hit that second for loop and because I did not reset IFS, it was causing issues.

Comment: BTW...I like your recommendation of using a while read loop instead of the for loop over command expansions. Thank you!